# Grep for a single line comment but exclude stuff like http://example.com

Tags: regex, linux, bash, grep

How can I use a regEx with grep so that I can check whether what I'm looking for is the first thing on the line ? What I want to do is find single line comments in a file, but I don't want to grep stuff line http://path, so there can't be anything behind // on the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ echo $'http://www.example.com\n   // single line comment' | grep "^ *//.*"
   // single line comment
```